# Adding Python member function to C++ class with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Using pybind11, embedding the interpreter and calling Python functions from C++ is relatively easy. However, I can't figure out how to add a Python member function to a C++ class.

What I have tried so far:

- Create a C++ class `HelloWorld`
- Create a `PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE` that wraps this class
- Import this module in a Python module which adds a member function to `HelloWorld`
- Import that module in `HelloWorld` itself

So on the C++ side I have:

```
class HelloWorld
{
public:
  void run() const
  {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    auto backend = py::module_::import("backend");

    // TODO: call HelloWorld._run()
  }

  char const *msg() const
  { return "Hello, World!"; }
};

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(frontend, m)
{
  py::class_<HelloWorld>(m, "HelloWorld")
    .def_static("msg", &HelloWorld::msg);
}
```

And on the Python side (`backend.py`)

```
from frontend import HelloWorld

HelloWorld._run = lambda self: print(self.msg())
```

But how do I now call `HelloWorld._run` from C++? Does this setup make sense at all? The idea is to extend existing C++ with different Python backends than can be hacked together quickly and exchanged at runtime.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. It seems to me that calling from python, to c++ and then back to python seems like a poor design. I would go one way or the other. Not both.

Comment: I would advise to forget the OO pattern of doing callback APIs by overriding methods. It's easy to call a method on a PyObject from Python-aware C++ code. You could pass around callbacks as function arguments, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Passing around callbacks from @maxy is an excellent suggestion. Your original code structure might make sense in principal but you are trying to add a member function to compiled C++ code, which doesn't really work. That can only happen at runtime, and is a valid approach but not as a member function.

The observer pattern is a design pattern designed for this:
https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3

This way you could maintain a series of callbacks which have been implemented in Python (akin to adding a member function) but are then called from C++. Essentially you just pass the function pointer to PyBind11, so have a binding which looks something like this:

```
m.def("add_python_callback", [](HelloWorld& self, const py::function& callback) { self.addPythonCallback(callback); });
```

An alternative is to integrate the Qt framework into your solution.
https://www.qt.io/product/framework

Qt has a 'metaobject compiler' which lets you use 'Signals' and 'Slots' to implement the observer patter without the boilerplate code described above. You could create a binding for `QObject::connect` and then add your python defined functions to your C++ class that way.